# how to change the background color of a listview?

Tags: android

my array list data:
John
John
Jack
Peter
Parker

the repeated names must have different background in the list view

how to do that?

```
ArrayList<listitem> data=
(ArrayList<listitem>)bundle.getSerializable("value");

sentItems = data; //names John,John,Jack....

final List<listitem> duplicates = new ArrayList<listitem>();
Set<listitem> listitemSet = new TreeSet<listitem>(new Comparator<listitem>() {
@Override
public int compare(ListItem o1, ListItem o2) {
return o1.getTitle().compareTo(o2.getTitle());
}
});
for(ListItem c : sentItems)
{
if(!listitemSet.add(c))
{
duplicates.add(c); //similar names added to the new list
}
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried, and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Make an array as given below as no of list item i suppose u have five items

```
int[] color_arr={Color.BLUE,Color.CYAN,Color.DKGRAY,Color.GREEN,Color.RED};
```

and after do in ur getView method of custome adapter as below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View row=convertView;

 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_custome, parent, false);
 row.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);// this set background color

 TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
 ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_list);

 textview.setText(data_text[position]);
 imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

 return (row);

}
```